# How to access value iterated on outer loop, after refactoring with .SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

I previously had a nested for loop, like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < outerObject.Count(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < outerObject[i].innerObject.Count(); j++)
    {
        DataRow myDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
        myDataRow["Column1"] = outerObject[i].PropertyX;
        myDataRow["Column2"] = innerObject[j].PropertyY;
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
    }
}
```

I have refactored the above using the LINQ `SelectMany` operator, but I am unsure how to access the value that I was previously accessing using `outerObject[i].PropertyX`

```
var objects = outerObject.SelectMany(x => x.innerObject)

foreach (var object in objects)
{
    DataRow myDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
    //myDataRow["Column1"] = // I am unsure how to get the value of outerObject[i].PropertyX here
    myDataRow["Column2"] = object.PropertyY;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
}
```

Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the outer iterator, you can do at least two things.

Perform your loop logic within the lambda by giving it `{ }` syntax or making it a full method

```
var objects = outerObject.SelectMany(x => 
{
    var result = x.InnerObject;

    DataRow myDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
    myDataRow["Column1"] = x.PropertyX;
    myDataRow["Column2"] = result.PropertyY;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);

    return result;
}
```

Cache the iterator using `new {...}` syntax, since nested lambdas have the same access as nested loops.

```
var objects = outerObject.SelectMany(x => x.InnerObject
    .Select(inner => new { Outer = x, Inner = inner } ));

foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    DataRow myDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
    myDataRow["Column1"] = obj.Outer.PropertyX;
    myDataRow["Column2"] = obj.Inner.PropertyY;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
}
```

Comment: There's no need for a statement lambda here as there's no reason for the local variable.  Just inline it.

Comment: @Servy that assumes nothing being done with the results, which would mean it'd be just as easy to use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I also think you might need `var @object` for this to compile

Comment: @Aravol Given the OP's code you're quite right that one could implement this just fine using two `foreach` loops.  He's given no reason not to do that.  It's exactly the same behavior you're getting out of `SelectMany` in this context.

Comment: I get that red wriggly line under 'SelectMany', saying: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.I‌​Enumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: @A_good_bull_named_Nihal if the type of `InnerObject` does not itself implement `IEnumerable<T>`, then `SelectMany` may as for type arguments.

Comment: @Aravol InnerObject is an array, it implements IEnumerable<T>

Comment: are you using the first or second variation? The second one is going to need a quick fix, looking back at it

Answer (score 3):

```
var objects = outerObject.SelectMany(x => new { outer = x, inner = x.innerObject })

foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    DataRow myDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
    myDataRow["Column1"] = obj.outer.PropertyX; 
    myDataRow["Column2"] = obj.inner.PropertyY;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
}
```

Comment: Gives me a compile error saying: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.